# Pull data from a database every minute and update on the website without refreshing

Tags: php, ajax, sqlite

I have this PHP page which connects to an SQLite database and reads data from it. The data is constantly being updated and I need the web page to refresh the data shown every minute. How to do it? I saw that Ajax helps in this but I am a complete Ajax newbie and I have to turn this in soon. Any pointers?

Sample code:

```
<?php
    $db = new SQLite3('some_db.db');
    $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM random_table');
?>
<table>
    <th>
        <td>ID</th><th>Value</th>
    </th>
    <?php
        while ($row = $query->fetchArray (SQLITE3_ASSOC)) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td><td><?php echo $row['val'];?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<pre>
JS CODE:
------------

function UpdateTable(){
$.ajax({
url: "script.php"
}).success(function(data) {
var d= JSON.parse(data);
  $('table#someID tr').remove();
  $('table#someID').append( d.tableContent );
});

}
$( document ).ready(function() {
setTimeout(UpdateTable(),60000);
});




PHP CODE: (script.php)
-----------

<?php
    $res = array();
    $res['result'] = false;
    $db = new SQLite3('some_db.db');
    $query = $db->query('SELECT * FROM random_table');
    $res['tableContent'] = "";

 while ($row = $query->fetchArray (SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
$res['tableContent'] .= "<tr><td>".$row['id']."</td><td>".$row['val']."</td></tr>";
}
    $res['result'] = true;
echo json_encode($res);

?>

</pre>
```